# Can git be made to track authors and file renames after a single file is split into several?

Tags: git, revision-history

Normally, when I do `git blame $filename`, git shows me various information for each line of code, like

```
^3333b include/Spec1.php (First Last)     function load($id) {
^5555b class/Spec.php    (Some One)           $id = ...
^6666b include/Spec1.php (First Last)         $var = ...
```

Namely,

- which commit it was,
- who updated the line last,
- and sometimes even what filename that line came from (when simple
  single-file renames have been performed).

In my case I seemed to have break that cycle, and git registered my change as a single global change made by me.

Namely, I had a large class called `Spec`, which contained code for several product lines.  I refactored out various code from the class towards several new classes.  When I do a commit, git detects those files as "new files".

That means that my new files will register as all new files made by me, in my name, and that lines inside them are "all new".

In essense, I lose:

- original author for each line - even though I just moved the line from one file to another not really having authored it, git sees it as new line regardless.
- old filenames used to house each line of code - when I do git blame, git now only sees the line as being housed in the new file created.  It loses track of file names where that line was housed at before.

Is there any way to not lose them while doing this complex commit?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "Is there anything I can do at this time to track the changes while retaining history?", but if you have committed the large Spec class, you are retaining history. Could you specify what more you are looking for?

Comment: see update  -- I am looking for retaining of "file renames" as part of history

Comment: I rewrote the question as well just now, adding "authors"

Comment: `git` does not track file or content renames/copies/movement. It tracks snapshots of the full project. Some of the tools (e.g. `blame`, `log`, `diff`, etc.) *detect* such changes when they are asked to, and have various options for tweaking the algorithms used to detect those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Git always does rename and copy detection dynamically, at the time you pick two different commits to compare.

When using `git blame`, the two commits you choose for each dynamic comparison come from the parent/child relationship.  The same is true for `git log -p` and `git show`.  When you run `git diff`, you decide for yourself which two commits to compare (rather than letting git pick them through the commit parent-ID).  In any case, the commits are eventually run through git's internal diff engine, either for an explicit `git diff` patch output (`git log -p`, `git show`) or for its change-finding effects (`git blame` just needs to see whether line 1234 is different in the child commit than in its parent).

You *also* can specify the "similarity threshold" for matching file renames—this is usually<sup>1</sup> done with the `-M` option—and whether you want to enable "find copies" and if so, whether to enable "find copies harder": these are usually done with `-C` (possibly repeated) or `--find-copies-harder`.  (`git blame` appears not to have the lattermost as a flag.  Also, `-M` in `git blame` doesn't look for file renames; instead, it changes the way "moved lines" are assigned.)

In this case, you probably want to set a low(ish) `-M` threshold and perhaps specify `-C` at least twice.  (Two `-C` options mean "look for code copied from other files in the current parent/child pair" while three `-C`s mean "look for code copied from any commit".)

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also configure `diff.renames = true` to enable the default `-M` value always; or, for turning on `-C` as well, `diff.renames = copies`.  This is specific to regular `diff`; `git blame` defines its `-M` and `-C` flags somewhat differently.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not sure I followed that.  When I do `git blame -C -C Spec1.php`, git thinks for a moment then still shows each line as being authored by me, today, when each line was in fact authored by someone else, during various times in the past.  To compare `git blame Spec.php` on the original file was showing various authors for each line, going a few years back.  With my refactor I lost that history.

Comment: I understand I need to do something at commit time perhaps?

Comment: Not so much "at commit time" but rather "at the time you run `git blame`".  You may need to lower the detection thresholds to find moved and copied code.  The default is to detect a block of 20 lines for `-M` and 40 lines for `-C`.  See the documentation for details.  (Something I glossed over here is that the precise definitions of `-M` and `-C` are different for `git blame` than for `git diff`, as well.)